# The game of Sevens

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, optimization, formation-of-numbers

There is a popular game, named [**Four fours**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours), where you have to find the shortest mathematical expression for every number from $1$ to $n$, using only the number $4$ and some operators.

My variant of this game is named **Sevens**, and you can only use the number $7$ and some math operators to obtain the other numbers.

Here is a **list of accepted operators** (along with their individual score):

- $+,-,\times, \div $ (**one** point)
- Parenthesis $( \ )$ (**zero** points)
- Exponentiation (**one** point)
- Square root) $\surd$ (rounded to lower integer) (**two** points)
- Factorial $!$ (**two** points)

**Note:** Logarithms and concatenation are explicitly not allowed! Implicit multiplication isn't allowed (eg. 7(3))

**How to calculate the score?**
The total score is the sum of all the partial scores you get with operations.
If you use an operation twice, you must add the partial score twice, of course.
The lower the score, the better it is!

Examples:
$7=(7+7)-7$ results in a score of $2$
$7=(7!)/(7-7/7)!$ results in a score of $7$

**Your task is to generate the numbers from $1$ to $30$ achieving the minimum possible score, using only the number $7$ and the above operations.**

Comment: Is there a limit on the number of operators allowed to be used (similar to Four fours)?

Comment: @MarkN It is an optimisation puzzle. You must find the *best* solution, not just any one that meets the limit. So, no, no limit.

Comment: Must we only use the number 7, or the digit 7? For instance, would a possible representation for 1 be '77/77'?

Comment: Can square root be rounded? Otherwise, I see no use for it.

Comment: Shouldn't you also place the restriction that you must use exactly seven 7s? Otherwise, why bother calling the game "Seven Sevens"?

Comment: As ghosts said, you must find the optimal solution, so no limits. 
You can only use the digit 7, 77 isn't allowed.  
Square root is rounded to lower integer (updated, sqrt is now 2 points worth). 
The name Seven sevens is a reference to Four fours.

Comment: @leoll2 The game Four Fours also (usually) has the restriction that the player must use four 4s in each equation. That's why it's named Four Fours.

Comment: @IanMacDonald This is a variation!

Comment: @JLee I've just renamed it to avoid confusion

Comment: Does division round down as well?

Comment: @Trenin No, division doesn't round.

Comment: As you see, in my "lateral thinking-answer" I used .7 notation. Do you accept it for the more standard one?

Comment: @AlbertMasclans No, .7 isn't accepted

Comment: Just a caveat: the square root operation implicitly has a 2 in it, because it's square root (as opposed to cube root or 4th root). If 7 is the only operand we're allowed to use, then we really can't use square root...but we should be able to use the 7th root and also x^7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my new answers, once again taking as base the Mark N contribution, but this time not using the binomial coefficient.

**Score: 107**

$1 = \frac{7}{7}$ [Score +1]

$2 = \sqrt{7}$ [Score +2]

$3 = \sqrt{7+7}$ [Score +3]

$4 = \sqrt{7+7+7}$ [Score +4]

$5 = 7-\sqrt{7}$ [Score +3]

$6 = 7-\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$7 = 7$ [Score +0]

$8 = 7+\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$9 = 7+\sqrt{7}$ [Score +3]

$10 = 7+\sqrt{7+7}$ [Score +4]

$11 =\sqrt{\sqrt{7}^7}$ [Score +5]

$12 = 7+7-\sqrt{7}$ [Score +4]

$13 = 7+7-\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +3]

$14 = 7 + 7$ [Score +1]

$15 = 7 + 7 + 7/7$ [Score +3]

$16 = 7 + 7 + \sqrt{7}$ [Score +4]

$17 = 7 + 7 +\sqrt{7+7}$ [Score +5]

$18 = \sqrt{7*7*7}$ [Score +4]

$19 = 7+7+7-\sqrt{7}$ [Score +5]

$20 = 7+7+7-\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +4]

$21 = 7+7+7$ [Score +2]

$22 = 7+7+7+\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +4]

$23 = 7+7+7+\sqrt{7}$ [Score +5]

$24 = (\sqrt{7+7+7})!$ [Score +6]

$25 = \frac{7*7*7+7}{7+7}$ [Score +5]

$26 = \sqrt{7!/7}$ [Score +5]

$27 = 7+7+7+7-\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +5]

$28 = 7+7+7+7$ [Score +3]

$29 = 7+7+7+7+\frac{7}{7}$ [Score +5]

$30 = \sqrt{\sqrt{7^7}}$ [Score +5]

Comment: I accept this answer as it looks optimal. If anybody comes with a better solution, I will accept his.

Answer (score 6):

So, here's a foundation to start on. **Score: 109**

$1 = 7/7$ [Score +1]

$2 = (7+7)/7$ [Score +2]

$3 = (7+7+7)/7$ [Score +3]

$4 = 7-(7+7+7)/7$ [Score +4]

$5 = 7-(7+7)/7$ [Score +3]

$6 = 7-7/7$ [Score +2]

$7 = 7$ [Score +0]

$8 = 7+7/7$ [Score +2]

$9 = 7+(7+7)/7$ [Score +3]

$10 = 7+(7+7+7)/7$ [Score +4]

$11 = 7+7-(7+7+7)/7$ [Score +5]

$12 = 7+7-(7+7)/7$ [Score +4]

$13 = 7+7-(7/7)$ [Score +3]

$14 = 7 + 7$ [Score +1]

$15 = 7 + 7 + 7/7$ [Score +3]

$16 = 7 + 7 + (7+7)/7$ [Score +4]

$17 = 7 + 7 +(7+7+7)/7$ [Score +5]

$18 = 7 + 7 + (7+7+7+7)/7$ [Score +6]*

$19 = 7+7+7-(7+7)/7$ [Score +5]

$20 = 7+7+7-(7/7)$ [Score +4]

$21 = 7+7+7$ [Score +2]

$22 = 7+7+7+(7/7)$ [Score +4]

$23 = 7+7+7+(7+7)/7$ [Score +5]

$24 = 7+7+7+(7+7+7)/7$ [Score +6]

$25 = 7+7+7+7-(7+7+7/7)$ [Score +7]*

$26 = 7+7+7+7-(7+7)/7$ [Score +6]

$27 = 7+7+7+7-(7/7)$ [Score +5]

$28 = 7+7+7+7$ [Score +3]

$29 = 7+7+7+7+(7/7)$ [Score +5]

$30 = 7+7+7+7+(7+7)/7$ [Score +6]

[1+2+3+4+3+2]+0+[2+3+4+5+4+3]+1+[3+4+5+6+5+4]+2+[4+5+6+7+6+5]+3+[5+6] = 113

This is a simple answer to help get the ball rolling.

**After improvements:**

*$18 = \sqrt{7*7*7} $ [Score +4] (oppose to 6)

*$25 = (7*7*7+7)/(7+7)$ [Score +5] (oppose to 7)

**Score: 113 - 2 - 2 = 109**

Comment: I've just updated the problem extending the numbers from 20 to 30, it seemed a bit too easy.

Comment: Here is an improvement: 18. $\sqrt{7*7*7}$ [Score + 4]

Comment: Wouldn't $25=5*5$ be better?

Comment: @Trenin, #5 * #5 would score (3 + 1 + 3), which is the same and I can't use square :( But the idea helps!

Comment: Your new 30 is still 6, not 5.

Comment: So it was, sorry about that :p

Comment: No prob - I posted a number of optimizations only to delete them shortly after!!!  I was quick enough that you didn't see them!

Comment: (7 * 7 * 7 + 7) / (7 + 7) = 25 with a score of 5.

Answer (score 2):

Taking Mark N answer (thanks a lot) I'll try to improve a bit, using some lateral thinking with the parentesis. Still, most of the credit goes to him.

EDIT: I decided to think even further outside the box and use $.7$ notation to improve the score.

**Score: 73**

$1 = \binom{7}{7}$ [Score +0]

$2 = \binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +1]

$3 = \binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$4 = \binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +3]

$5 = 7-\binom{7}{7}-\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$6 = 7-\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +1]

$7 = 7$ [Score +0]

$8 = 7+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +1]

$9 = 7+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$10 = \frac{7}{.7}$ [Score +1]

$11 = \frac{7}{.7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$12 = \frac{7}{.7}+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +3]

$13 = 7+7-\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$14 = 7 + 7$ [Score +1]

$15 = 7 + 7  +\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$16 = 7 + 7 + \binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +3]

$17 = \sqrt{\binom{7+7}{7}^.7}$ [Score +4]

$18 = \sqrt{7*7*7}$ [Score +4]

$19 = \frac{7+7}{.7}-\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +3]

$20 = \frac{7+7}{.7}$ [Score +2]

$21 = \binom{7}{\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}}$ [Score +1]

$22 = \binom{7}{\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +2]

$23 = \binom{7}{\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}}+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +3]

$24 = (7+\binom{7}{7})*(\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7}+\binom{7}{7})$ [Score +4]

$25 = (7*7*7+7)/(7+7)$ [Score +5]

$26 = \sqrt{7!/7}$ [Score +5]

$27 = 7+7+7+7-\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +4]

$28 = 7+7+7+7$ [Score +3]

$29 = 7+7+7+7+\binom{7}{7}$ [Score +4]

$30 = \frac{7+7+7}{.7}$ [Score +3]

I'll be editing and improving when I come up with new ones.

Comment: The binomial coefficient isn't in the list of accepted operators. If you want to use it, you must build it with factorials.

Comment: I just wanted to think a bit outside the box. I'll post another more canonical answer.

Comment: Ithink it breaks the 'spirit' of the puzzle, but I enjoy your lateral thinking on the parentheses notation.

Comment: also 7 above 7 is still 7/7 so thats 1 point whenever you use it

Comment: @Vajura as said I tried to be a bit creative in here when using the parentheses. leoll2 clearly said that binomial coefficient is not an accepted operator so the answer is only kept as curiosity, with no intention of being the best solution to the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are my answers, which are a combination of some prior answers and my improvements on certain ones:**

**Score: 92**

$1 = \frac{7}{7} \ \  \ \ $ [Score +1]

$2 = \sqrt{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +2]

$3 = \sqrt{7+7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$4 = \sqrt{7+7+7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$5 = 7-\sqrt{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$6 = 7-\frac{7}{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +2]

$7 = 7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +0]

$8 = 7+\frac{7}{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +2]

$9 = 7+\sqrt{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$10 = 7+\sqrt{7+7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$11 =\sqrt{7(7)7} \ - \ 7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$12 = 7+7-\sqrt{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$13 = 7+7-\frac{7}{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$14 = 7 + 7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +1]

$15 = 7 + 7 + 7/7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$16 = 7 + 7 + \sqrt{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$17 = \sqrt{7(7(7) - 7)} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$18 = \sqrt{7(7)7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +2]

$19 = \sqrt{7(7)7 + 7(7)} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$20 = 7+7+7-\frac{7}{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$21 = 7+7+7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +2]

$22 = 7+7+7+\frac{7}{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$23 = 7+7+7+\sqrt{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +5]

$24 = \sqrt{(7(7) - 7)(7 + 7)} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$25 = \sqrt{7(7)7} \ + \ 7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$26 = \sqrt{7(7)7 \ + \ 7(7)7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$27 = \sqrt{(7(7) + 7)7 \ +  \ 7(7)7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +4]

$28 = 7+7+7+7 \ \ \ \ $ [Score +3]

$29 = 7+7+7+7+\frac{7}{7} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +5]

$30 = \sqrt{\sqrt{7^7}} \ \ \ \ $ [Score +5]

**[1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 2]  +  [0 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 4]  +  [3 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 2]  +  [3 + 4 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 4]  +  [3 + 3 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 5]  =  92**

.
.

**The above solution will have to be accepted as best so far, else the problem poser is a cheat.**

Answer (score 1):

The answers I'm sure of:

$1=7/7$

$2=(7+7)/7$

$6=7-7/7$

$7=7$

$8=7+7/7$

$14=7+7$

Comment: i got the same thing for 7  :)